# How to run a python function from a file using python commandline?

Tags: python, command-line, ide

I am using `python.exe`.

I tried:

```
C:/myfile.py

python C:/myfile.py

python "C:/myfile.py"
```

It always says "invalid syntax". The code is this one:
https://github.com/paulnasca/paulstretch_python/blob/master/paulstretch_stereo.py#L150

So not sure if the file has bugs or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: where are you running it from?

Comment: python.exe, it's the commandline tool I think.

Comment: when you just enter `python` what happens?

Comment: Please be more specific. Given the number of questions you've asked, you should be familiar with the process. Python never just says "invalid syntax" it gives you the line inside the code so you can isolate the error. Btw, [it works in Python 2](http://ideone.com/b0K0So) and [shows a different error message in Python 3](http://ideone.com/wTIOE1).

Comment: This is what I am getting: http://i.imgur.com/OM22glu.png

Comment: I just want to run that code file so I can use it to process some audio files. I know how to do that but I can't get python to run it.

Comment: your screenshot shows that you are already in the Python interpreter. Trying to run `python` again will result in an error, of course.

Comment: do `from myfile import paulstretch`

Comment: Yes but some people suggested using the python command. I don't know how to call a py file. This is what I get when I do that: http://i.imgur.com/dQwDZiY.png

Comment: you don't run scripts from the interpreter, just use `python your_file.py` from a cmd prompt, the script also needs args passed

Comment: How do you do that? If I type the path of the file, then Cmd/Windows just opens the code using notepad. I don't see python in the list of Open With -> Other programs list.

Comment: from a cmd shell type, `python C:/myfile.py `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you are already in the Python interpreter. Trying to run python again will result in an error. Exit the interpreter by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Make sure you have downloaded the **complete** `paulstretch_stereo.py` file. Put the file in the same directory as the files you want to process. Then, from the **Windows** command line, run `python paulstretch_stereo.py --help` and the program's options should print out.

By the way, make sure you have NumPy and SciPy installed, otherwise the program won't run.

Comment: Thanks, I installed numpy and scipy but do I not have to type the path of paulstretch.py?

Comment: @JoanVenge not if you're in the directory that contains the file.

Answer (score 1):

What you get when you run `python.exe` directly is called the *interactive interpreter*.

The usual way to run a python module is simply providing it as a command-line option to the python process:

```
python C:/myfile.py
```

This command is provided from your command-line, *not from the interactive interpreter*.